# CSS select object between two <br>

Tags: html, css, r, css-selectors, rvest

Very very new to CSS and HTML language, I might say a lot of non-sense. And I really can't find the answer that I'm look for. I think it's because I don't know how to search correctly... lacking of vocabulary...So please forgive me.
So I'm doing some web scraping on R with rvest package. I want to select the line between two br lines as follow :

```
<div class="description">
   <a href= "blabla" title ="a wonderful apple cultivated by snow 
   white herself" data-position = "1">  
   <span class="origine"> snow white</span>    
   </a>
    <br>
    "a wonderful apple cultivated by snow white herself"
    <br>
    <span class="price">€5,000</span>
    <br class="clearboth">
    <span class="slug"> Exclusivité</span>
</div>
```

So I'm basically trying to extract the line "a wonderful apple cultivated by snow white herself" not int the title but between the two lines of br... I tried to use the following code in R

```
description_node_html <- html_nodes(page,"br *")
description_node_html <- html_nodes(page,"br~br")
description_node_html <- html_nodes(page,"div br")
```

or even this one inspired by a research result

```
description_node_html <- html_nodes(page,"('br').nextUntil('br')")
```

Unfortunately non of them work. At the best I selected empty spaces...
So would you please tell me how to select this line between two lines of br please ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: not familiar with R syntax, but: Can you find the parent of the `br` element, and then loop through its children to find the index of that `br`, check for the index+2 also being a `br`, and select the index+1?

Comment: Thank you Peril, but it doesn't work...